# Break statement in python 2.6

Tags: python, loops, break

```
primes = set([1,2,3])

for r in range(1,20):

    if (r not in primes):
        for q in range(2,r):
            if r % q == 0:
                break
            primes.add(r)

print primes

set([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19])
```

How 9 and 15 can be excluded here from the primes list?

Answer (score 2):

Use [for-else](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) loop:

```
primes = set([1,2,3])

for r in range(1,20):

    if (r not in primes):
        for q in range(2,r):
            if r % q == 0:
                break
        else:
            #this will execute only if the for-loop completed without any breaks 
            primes.add(r)

print primes
#set([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19])
```